# Trying to get windows scheduled task state in zabbix

Tags: powershell, zabbix

I've just started using the following template to monitor my windows scheduled tasks:
https://share.zabbix.com/operating-s...hes-planifiees

So it works perfect but the only problem is it doesn't pull the scheduled task state ( Disabled or Enabled ).
Now, I tried to edit the PowerShell script associated with the template my self and added the following lines:

```
switch ($ITEM) {
"TaskStatus" {
[string] $name = $ID
$name1 = $name.replace('&acirc;','â').replace('&agrave;','à ').replace('&ccedil;','ç').replace('&eacute;','é') .replace('&egrave;','è').replace('&ecirc;','ê')
$pathtask = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "*" -TaskName "$name1"
$pathtask1 = $pathtask.Taskpath
$taskResult = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "$pathtask1" -TaskName "$name1" | Select State
Write-Output ($taskResult.Status)
```

But it doesn't seem to work, I get the error below when I try to execute the item:

```
Value of type "string" is not suitable for value type "Numeric (unsigned)". Value ""
```

I get empty value for some reason, Anyone here can help me please? :P

Thank you!
Tags: None

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:
https://github.com/Iakim/Zabbix-ScheduledTask

He added TaskState to his powershell script and it works.